# Draw rectangle multiple times in new position not working

Tags: android, dynamic, android-asynctask, draw, shapes

Each time I create a new rectangle with this code it does not work, I can only draw to a specified position, if I use a variable to change position on execution it does not draw anything.

Inside a Asynctask method:

```
rect = new desenho(main.this, x, y);
```

Which calls this:

```
public class desenho extends View{
    
    int x, y;
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    
    public desenho(Context context, int x, int y) {
        super(context);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(width, y);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(c);
        c.drawRect(5, y, width-5, y+x, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your background isn't black is it? :). IT looks like you might be drawing a black rectangle on a black background. Also you can try using the debugger to step through the code to see what the values are when drawRect gets called.

Comment: in this case it does not draw anything, only i do something like this:
c.drawRect(5, 5, width-5, 100, mPaint);

Comment: No the background is white, and i checked the values on system.out and they are correct.. i don't know what is wrong... Maybe the cause is the AsyncTaskMethod ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you want the size to be independent of position. For that, these requirements must be met in your Canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint):

- left - right = a
- top - bottom = b

where a, b are constant. Example:

```
c.drawRect(xPos, yPos, xPos + width - 1, yPos + height - 1, mPaint);
```

You see in this example that

- left - right = xPos - (xPos + width - 1) = 1 - width
- top - bottom = yPos - (yPos + height - 1) = 1 - height

Both are constant → size is constant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However if i undertand correctly i am doing that, i only change the top and bottom coordinate of the rectangle, and they are always a constant.. i will analise your answer deeply when i get home.

Comment: It seems you're right. At first glance, I thought x as part of the bottom parameter was referring to some horizontal property, but now I see it really is constant.

Comment: By the way, the rightmost pixel has index width-1, so if you want your rectangle centered, width-5 should be width-6

Comment: @ Joel Sjögren, when i create a series of rectangles with this: c.drawRect(5, top, width-5, top+bottom, mPaint);  It doesn't work (first image).                                                      But if i create only one: c.drawRect(5, 5, width-5, 5+bottom, mPaint); It works (second image). It seems the cause is the top variable which is incremented during runtime... Images: http://imgur.com/a/xfJYj